# Log4j2 RollingFile doesn't work when using ${sys:jboss.server.log.dir}

Tags: log4j2, wildfly-8, rollingfileappender

Everything works fine when I have a rolling file configured as so:

---

RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender" 
   fileName="/applicationLogs/CTMSApplicationService-${hostName}.log"
   filePattern="/applicationLogs/CTMSApplicationService-${hostName}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log"

---

BUT as soon as I use the ${sys:jboss.server.log.dir} for the "root" of my log location the primary log gets created but nothing ever rolls.  The log file just gets appended to:

---

RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender" 
   fileName="**${sys:jboss.server.log.dir}**/CTMSApplicationService-${hostName}.log"
   filePattern="**${sys:jboss.server.log.dir}**/CTMSApplicationService-${hostName}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">

---

The value of ${sys:jboss.server.log.dir}="E:\Wildfly-8.1.0.Final\standalone\log"

Is it because the fileName can handle the Winblows "E:\" and the filePattern can not?

Comment: That looks/smells like it!  Thanks so much.  For now "../standalone/log/<filename>" works just fine and those locations aren't going to change anytime soon....it just eats at the purist in me.

...wait a second...

OK; now I'm over it.  Apparently I'm far less of a purist than I led myself to believe. (it is more important to get it done!)

Thank you for directing me to this!

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-829
This is fixed in the master branch and will be included in the upcoming 2.1 release.